# How to use Env in mod_substitute?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, geoip

Okay, I'm not very strong at htaccess. I have a code:

```
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US LinkC example1
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute s/example2/env=LinkC/ni
```

I'm trying to substitue concrete content in my page. And all text were substituted to env=LinkC, not to example1 as it should to be. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is *combine* [Substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html) with [server side includes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html).  Here is the specific code block that I used

```
<Location "/css">
    # This specifies the filter sequence
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE;INCLUDES text/css

    # This specifies that SSI should be allowed.
    Options Includes


    ProxyPass "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css"
    # This converts the string I want and replaces them with SSI directives
    Substitute 's|https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/|<!--#echo var="REQUEST_SCHEME" -->://<!--#echo var="HTTP_HOST" -->/s/|'
</Location>
```

To help with figuring out what variables you have available you can temporarily do this

```
Substitute 's|https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/|<!--#printenv -->/s/|'
```

I used this in [my Google Fonts Proxy image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/trajano/google-fonts) [[sources]](https://github.com/trajano/google-fonts-proxy-docker).

Answer (score 0):

mod_substitute doesn't do this. The replacement strings are static, or are back references to the search string regular expression, not request-specific.

Take a look at the server side includes feature instead:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

Pages utilizing this feature can be simple templates which can have request-based substitutions and incorporate some simple conditional logic.